# How to write a new layer to PostgreSQL from QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pyqgis

The PyQGIS cookbook states that QgsVectorFileWriter can write vector layers to any format supported by OGR:

https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#writing-vector-layers

However when I try this I get an error (based on the .source() of an existing layer):

```
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, u'dbname=\'snorf\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'snorf\' sslmode=disable key=\'id\' srid=4326 type=POINT table="public"."mynewlayer" (the_geom) sql=', 'UTF-8', layer.crs(), 'PostgreSQL')
```

This returns `QgsVectorFileWriter.ErrCreateDataSource`.

I don't have any problems modifying existing PostgreSQL layers, and I can write a new layer to the database using `ogr2ogr` without issue.

- How do I create a new empty postgres layer?
- How do I save an existing layer into a postgres database?

Comment: Any progress on using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I've found it to create a new table in postgres using the QtSql module. I'm sure there must still be a way to do this from QgsVectorLayerWriter, but I haven't found it yet.

The code below creates a new table called 'testing' with an autoincrementing 'id' attribute and adds it to the legend.

```
from qgis.core import *

from PyQt4 import QtSql

database = 'yourdatabase'
username = 'youruser'
table = 'testing'
srid = 4326
dimension = 2
typmod = 'POINT'

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection('localhost', '5432', database, username, '')
uri.setDataSource('public', table, 'the_geom', '')

db.setHostName(uri.host())
db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
db.setUserName(uri.username())
db.setPassword(uri.password())

ok = db.open()
if ok:
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
    if not query.exec_('CREATE TABLE {table} (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY)'.format(table=table)):
        raise RuntimeError('Failed to create table')
    if not query.exec_('''SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', '{table}', 'the_geom', {srid}, '{typmod}', {dimension})'''.format(table=table, srid=srid, typmod=typmod, dimension=dimension)):
        raise RuntimeError('Failed to add geometry column to table')
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), table, 'postgres')
    if layer.isValid():
        QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to open database connection: {}'.format(db.lastError().driverText()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to go through the source code of DB Manager plugin to get to the bottom of this! I don't know why they didn't mention it in PyQGIS cookbook, but in order to write to the database another (but similar) function have to be used: [QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer()](http://qgis.org/api/2.8/classQgsVectorLayerImport.html). Also notice that provider name is `postgres` instead of `PostgreSQL` O_o and no word in documentation about it...

Here is the example:

```
uri = "dbname='snorf' host=localhost port=5432 user='snorf' password='password' key=gid type=POINT table=\"public\".\"mynewlayer\" (geom) sql="
crs_id = 4326
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_id, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
error = QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(layer, uri, "postgres", crs, False, False)
if error[0] != 0:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error', error[1], QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### QGIS 3.x

In QGIS 3.x, you can write a layer to Postgis using [`QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayerExporter.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayerexporter#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer), as documented.

#### Postgresql provider `uri`

The Postgresql provider `uri` indicates the destination database server, table, geometry column and primary key field.

It depends on how you connect to the database.

If you provide *hostname*, *database*, *username* and *password*, the `uri` should be like:

```py
uri = 'dbname=\'miebiom\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'geobox\' password=\'geobox\' sslmode=disable table="public"."import" (geom) key=\'id\''
```

If you use [libpq services](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) to connect, just use:

```py
uri = 'service=covid table="public"."import" (geom) key=\'id\''
```

#### Usage example

In the following example, an existent layer called `distrito` is written to a table `public.import`.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
lyr = project.mapLayersByName('distrito')[0]

uri = 'dbname=\'miebiom\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'geobox\' password=\'geobox\' sslmode=disable table="public"."import" (geom) key=\'id\' '

err = QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(lyr, uri, "postgres", lyr.crs() )

if err[0] != QgsVectorLayerExporter.NoError:
    print('Import layer {} failed with error {}'.format( lyr.name(), err) )
else:
    print('Layer {} import ok'.format( lyr.name() ) )
```

#### Options

You can add additional options to `QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer()`.

Common options to all providers:

- `overwrite` (False, if not provided)
- `forceSinglePartGeometryType` (False, if not provided)

Postgresql provider specific option:

- `lowercaseFieldNames` (False, if not provided)

Usage example with all options:

```py
err = QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(lyr, uri, "postgres", lyr.crs(), 
        options = { "overwrite": True, "forceSinglePartGeometryType": True, "lowercaseFieldNames": True } )
```

#### Non geographic layers

For non geographic layers, just remove the geometry column from the `uri`. You can check if the layer is geographic or not with [`lyr.geometryType()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.geometryType).

#### Other examples on QGIS unit tests

A good source of usage examples are QGIS unit tests. Follow this [link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/253c706b5cdb0f5106453103cf61540c4d0c98a4/tests/src/python/test_provider_postgres.py#L1098), for usage examples written by QGIS developers.